# Problemas de envío con PHPmailer

Tags: php, servidor, php7

Tengo un formulario de contacto donde estoy realizando el envió de mail de la siguiente forma:

```
$contenido2 .= "Cotendio a mostrar";
$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$subject2 = 'Formulario de Cotiza';
$subject2 = utf8_decode($subject2);
$mail2->Subject = $subject2;
$mail2->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail2->From     = 'no-reply@noresponder.cl';
$mail2->FromName = 'Contacto';
$mail2->MsgHTML($contenido2);

$mail2->AddAddress('no-reply@noresponder.cl');
$mail2->AddCC('grupo@grupo.cl');
$mail2->AddCC('mi-correo@grupo.cl');
```

El problema es que a mi correo llega perfecto el contacto, pero al correo grupo@grupo.cl (administrador por varios usuarios) no llega la copia de este correo, pero si aparece como que fue enviado.

Para descartar errores hice lo siguiente:

- Revise si estaba en SPAM y nada.
- Revise si el correo bloquea los envíos desde el servidor y no es eso, porque con otros formularios que están en otras VPS del server si funciona.
- Revise el log de error del servidor y no muestra nada.
  Cual puede ser el error ? Se me ocurre que puede estar en alguna configuración del server...

Me ayudan por favor.

Comment: Prueba a enviarlo vía `SMTP`

Comment: ¿Si pones a `grupo@grupo.cl` como destinatario principal sí llega o tampoco llega?

Comment: No, no le llega si lo dejo como destinatario.

Comment: Entonces intenta capturar eventuales errores (con las herramientas de PHPMailer) para que sepas con más precisión  a qué se debe.

Comment: suena a que esta mal escrito

Comment: Intenta habilitar la el debugeo para ver sí ahí te muestra un error: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`